# How can I implement ActivityIndicator in App.xml

Tags: xamarin.forms, loader, activity-indicator

In MainPage, I implemented the login functionality of my application. After login, it will redirect to the dashboard. The user will directly redirect to the dashboard If the user already login the application.

On the MainPage.XML, I implemented ActivityIndicator. This will display to the users who are login into the app the first time.

Now I need to implement the ActivityIndicator in the App.xml page. because if the user already did login,the mainPage won't display to the user. It will directly redirect to the dashboard.I need to display ActivityIndicator before redirecting to dashboard

How can I implement the Activity indicator in the App.XML page?

**What I tried in App.XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="VSS.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actIndicator2"
                    WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Color="Black"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.cs:**

```
public partial class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            //MainPage = new VendorTabbedPage();
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "***SQLite.db3");
            SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTable<LoginSqlLiteM>();
            var data = db.Table<LoginSqlLiteM>();
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["isAddContact"] = "";

            if (data.Count() != 0)
            {
                actIndicator2.IsVisible = true;
                actIndicator2.IsRunning = true;

                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainMasterDetailPage())
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                };
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                }; 
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Help me.

Comment: First of all, App.xaml is not a page that is displayed on your UI and hence cannot hold a UI element. What a better way of doing this would be adding a screen like your splash screen that holds this indicator and that actually does your navigation as well to make it look smoother! FYI, it will only show if you await an async call

Comment: You should rather display activity indicator in your MainMasterDetailPage when content is loading. I don't see the point in postponing navigation. If you need to inform user that he is being redirected to content I would rather use toast that will stay on screen during navigation process and is not attached to current view.

Comment: @FreakyAli, How can I implement a splash screen?

Comment: It's basically a screen that does all your calculations and DB calls and gets you the appropriate data on the required screen, Whilst doing the same you can show an activity indicator on that screen!

Comment: You can use `IsVisible` this property to control the `ActivityIndicator` appear or disappear.